# React Native - botão de um arquivo js chamando uma função ou variável em outro arquivo js

Tags: javascript, react, react-native

Preciso de um help aqui:

Tenho 2 arquivos js: Header/index.js e Main/index.js

Na Header/index.js tem um botão: `<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {}} />`

Na Main/index.js tem:

```
const onPressTiming = () => {
    Animated.timing(translateY, {toValue: 380, duration: 300, useNativeDriver: true,}).start();
  }
```

Preciso fazer funcionar o botão na `Header/index.js`, quando clicado executar a "*cost onPressTiming*" da `Main/index.js`

Simplificando, Um botão de um arquivo js chamando função ou variável dentro de outro arquivo js.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode enviar a função como props para o seu componente Header. Para fazer isso, no contrutor do seu arquivo "Main", você pode fazer o bind com a função que deseja utilizar.

No exemplo abaixo, o componente "Main" enviar a função "deletar" para o componente "Excluir".

```
import {Container} from "./styles.js";
import Excluir from "../../components/Excluir/index";
export default class Main extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.deletar = this.deletar.bind(this);
  }

  deletar = async id => {
    try {
      //Executar comandos
    } catch (error) {
      //Em caso de erro
    }
  };

  
  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
      
        <Excluir
          deletar={this.deletar}
          codigo={1}
        />

      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

No seu componente "Excluir", você poderia usar a função criada na "Main" desta forma:

```
import {Container, RemoveButton, Title, Subtitle, TextButton} from "./styles.js";
const Excluir = ({deletar, codigo }) => (
  <Container>
    <Title>Remover</Title>
    <Subtitle>Tem certeza que deseja excluir?</Subtitle>
    <RemoveButton onPress={() => deletar(codigo)}><TextButton>Sim</TextButton></RemoveButton>
  </Container>
);
```

Comment: Blz! Obrigado, ficou bem claro!